# Phonegap build google maps plugin error

Tags: google-maps, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am using phonegap build. This is my first hybrid app. the target Android version is 5.1. I'm trying to use the google maps plugin for phonegap - using the syntax used on the phonegap build website. I am adding this line to my config file.

```
<plugin name="plugin.google.maps.menusito" spec="1.2.5" source="pgb">
```

I am however running into problems I do get the error Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: /home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/plugins/dfe3d26a-1c56-11e5-bd0a-22000ba705f9

Anyone got an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. -- Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this info was relevant. I updated my post.

Comment: It seems Hirbod (the current manager of the plugin) failed something. Report at https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps